# Open file with O_APPEND on FreeBsd and Linux doesn't look like an atomic operation?

Tags: c, system

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024*1024*100
#define FILE_MODE       (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pfd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, FILE_MODE);
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
    printf("errr fork\n");
    exit(0);
    } else if (pid == 0)
    {
        int cfd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, FILE_MODE);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            if (write(cfd, "child\n", 6) == -1)
        {
        printf("err in child\n");
        exit(0);
        }

        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        if (write(pfd, "parent\n", 7) == -1)
    {
        printf("error in parent\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test environment 1:

uname -a
FreeBSD freebsd 10.0-RELEASE-p12 FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE-p12 #0: Tue Nov  4 05:07:17 UTC 2014     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

clang -v
FreeBSD clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final 183502) 20130610
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0
Thread model: posix

Test environment 2:

uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Some lines lost

```
$ sort data.txt | uniq -c
1000000 child
982937 parent
```

O_APPEND doesn't seem to work as the man page said it should.

Can anyone give me more information about this?

Comment: I can repro the problem with 2 file descriptors on Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite. If you used a single file descriptor, rather than two separate file descriptors, do you get the correct result? I do. Is the trouble that the parent process writes some data to the file, and then the child truncates the file? We'd need to identify the lines with an ID number...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, if use a single fd, I got the correct result. Because child process just copied the fd from parent, they shared the file table in kernel, so the file offset also shared.

Comment: use O_TRUNC in child will delete some "parent" lines. but it can't make O_APPEND works as a atomic operation. I'am reading the APUE SE, the code just want to test if the O_APPEND can works like what man page said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that when the child opens the file, it truncates it, losing the data that the parent has already written to the file, leaving the parent with a short count.  It is likely that it will always be the parent with the short count because the child has to open the file a second time, and file opening is an expensive operation.  If the first open was moved so it was only in the parent, the timing would be different; it's possible that the child would sometimes have fewer entries.

Modified code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILE_MODE       (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pfd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, FILE_MODE);
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("errr fork\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        int cfd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, FILE_MODE);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            char buffer[32];
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "child%07d\n", i);
            if (write(cfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1)
            {
                printf("err in child\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            char buffer[32];
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "parent%07d\n", i);
            if (write(pfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1)
            {
                printf("error in parent\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One time when I ran it, the output started:

```
parent0000052
parent0000053
parent0000054
parent0000055
parent0000056
parent0000057
parent0000058
parent0000059
parent0000060
parent0000061
parent0000062
parent0000063
parent0000064
child0000000
parent0000065
child0000001
parent0000066
child0000002
parent0000067
```

So, the parent had executed 52 writes before the child truncated the file (0..51).  The counts agree:

```
$ grep -o -E 'child|parent' data.txt | sort | uniq -c
1000000 child
999948 parent
$
```

Comment: Er... now I understand why you and  user3159253 talk about O_TRUNC.. Thank you all very much...